# Mismatch on string of resistors for DC bus voltage sensing

Tags: resistors, analog, identification, voltage-divider

In the picture below, you can see a string of 10 resistors used for DC bus voltage sensing. I think that the blue resistors (the original ones) are 400k/1W. The colors are: yellow, black, black, orange. One of the resistors got open, and I replaced it with the one you see different in the string, the one in the red circle. It's a 390k/1W resistor. The equipment worked well for a couple of hours, then the resistor in the white circle got open.

Do you think the new resistor could have affected the string so that a new resistor got damaged?

I think we have a variation of 10k in the string with the addition of a 390k, which leads to increase the current.

[image]

Comment: How do you get 400K from those markings? That is a green stripe, right?

Comment: The color seems confusing. I see yellow. In addition, I took out a good resistor and measured it. The meter says 400k.

Comment: 10K in 5*400k (2M) is only 0.5%. I would suspect either: whatever caused the first resistor to fail had a similar effect on the second, and/or heat damage while replacing the first made it worse.

Comment: What voltage is this circuit sensing? To get 1W dissipated in a 400K resistor you'd need 632V so that's over 6kV across the whole chain. Hard to believe it's burned out.

Comment: The device is fed with 480 VAC, so it should sense a DC bus of around 700V.

Comment: I don't know if it's 1W. I'm judging by the size of the resistor which is 0207.

Comment: The meter says 400k. Did you measure this in circuit? If so, you measurement may be completely wrong (in other words: don't measure in circuit if you're not 100% what you're doing). If not, did you also take into account you put about 10 Meg from the multimeter across the "400"k resistor? So, if "it says 400k" the resistor may in fact be 417k ohm?

Comment: I measured the resistor out of the circuit.

Comment: Is the "good resistor" you took out actually the second failure? The soldering on it looks different.

Comment: Yes, it is. Can I replace it with another 390k resistor? I thought of replacing all of the resistors with another value, as I did not find the original one in the market. Of course, it's extra work and it can make the circuit vulnerable since it must be soldered carefully.

Comment: You need to pay attention to @BrianDrummond's first comment. If you don't determine why the **first** resistor failed and remove that fault condition then you will just keep blowing resistors. And when you are replacing resistors in a circuit like this you must also consider their voltage rating and whether they are flameproof.

Comment: OK that adds to the heat damage hypothesis. I'd replace with 390K and good luck. Any more failures and I'd source 400K parts.

Comment: As to the power rating, it's confusing for me that I see both 1W and 2/5W in the same package 0207. According to @Finbarr comment, then 2/5W would work.

Comment: What voltage do you measure at the first resistor?

Comment: I haven't measured voltage. I could do it, I just would have to make sure I take the proper safety considerations as there's a high voltage in there. I will draw a schematic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think the new resistor could have affected the string so that a
>   new resistor got damaged?

I doubt it, the resistor strings look like they're part of different circuits. If the resistor did open, then it was most likely from heat. Each string appears to share the same trace (it looks like in each string the resistors are in series and each string is independent). This means each string has 5 resistors in series. If the resistors are in series and the same value, they should have mostly the same voltage across them and dissipate the same power.

If they died a heat death, then it could have been almost any resistor in the string, if the strings are independent then there is no relation between the death of the resistor circled in white or red.

Comment: Surely those components at the left hand side of the chains are linking them together?

Comment: That looks like some kind of filter with two independent channels similar to the circuits below. If I had my guess, they are dropping a high voltage signal down to a more manageable level. Don't know why it would kill the first one though. I think they are independent channles, the circuitry to the left is an isolator and the circuits in between are filters.

Comment: Perhaps, but to me it looks more like a differential amplifier based around an MC33272 dual opamp.

Comment: I see that now, you can barely make out the numbers on the IC. It is definitely a MC33272. Maybe some kind of current sensing application?